# Jquery multiple id link to toggle different div

Tags: jquery, html, click, toggle

I have these links to toggle corresponding divs that `display:hidden;` How can I group them ? Because I have more than 10 of them.

```
            $('a#toggle-b').click(function() {
            $('.toggle-b').toggle('slow').css('display','inline-block').siblings().hide('slow');
            $('.describe').fadeIn('slow');
            return false
            });

            $('a#toggle-c').click(function() {
            $('.toggle-c').toggle('slow').css('display','inline-block').siblings().hide('slow');
            $('.describe').fadeIn('slow');
            return false
            });

            $('a#toggle-d').click(function() {
            $('.toggle-d').toggle('slow').css('display','inline-block').siblings().hide('slow');    
            $('.describe').fadeIn('slow');
            return false
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('a[id^=toggle-]').click(function() {
    $('.' + this.id ).toggle('slow').css('display','inline-block').siblings().hide('slow');
    $('.describe').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: This is the perfect that works, because I have other anchor links with no class, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
     $('.'+this.id).toggle('slow').css('display','inline-block').siblings().hide('slow');
     $('.describe').fadeIn('slow');
            return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var cls = '.'+$(this).attr('id');
        $(cls).toggle('slow').css('display','inline-block').siblings().hide('slow');
        $('.describe').fadeIn('slow');
        return false
        });​
```